# First child without certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to write a CSS rule to select the first child of an element without a specific class?

example:

```
<div>
    <span class="common-class ignore"></span>
    <span class="common-class ignore"></span>
    <span class="common-class"></span>
    <span class="common-class"></span>
</div>
```

In this case I would like to select the first `span` without class `ignore`.
I tried this, but didn't seem to work:

```
.common-class:first-child:not(.ignore) {
    ...some rules...
}
```

**UPDATE**:

If I add a class to the parent div named `parent-class`, a modified version of the selector suggested by Jukka works except when the first `span` with class `ignore` comes after the first one without. The above-mentioned selector is the following:

```
.parent-class > .common-class.ignore + .common-class:not(.ignore) {
    ...some rules...
}
```

Comment: what if you try this way check DEMO. http://jsbin.com/jozibazi/1/edit

Comment: In this specific case: `.ignore + .common-class {/* style the first */}` *might* work; but it's probably quite fragile (and this approach would style an element of `.common-class` *every time* it followed an element of `.ignore`).

Answer (score 19):

This question is similar to [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class), except for the first element *without* a class. As mentioned, `:first-child:not(.ignore)` represents an element that is the first child of its parent and does not have the class "ignore", not the first child matching the rest of the selector.

You can use the overriding technique with a sibling combinator that I've described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) to the linked question, replacing the class selector with the `:not()` pseudo-class containing a class selector:

```
.common-class:not(.ignore) {
    /* Every span without class .ignore, including the first */
}

.common-class:not(.ignore) ~ .common-class:not(.ignore) {
    /* Revert above declarations for every such element after the first */
}
```

Comment: Not if you have `.cc|.cc.ignore|.cc|.cc.ignore'... etc. You cannot stop CSS after first match. It will continue searching for the pattern until the end of DOM. (or DOOM?)

Answer (score 7):

This selects **all** span with a `.common-class` and without an `.ignore` class.

```
span.common-class:not(.ignore) {
  color: blue;
}
```

But, because we want to select only the first one, you can override the siblings that follow with the `~` selector.

```
span.common-class:not(.ignore) ~ span {
  color: black;   /* or   color: inherit; */
}
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/baxexiri/1/edit?html,css,output)**

---

If you are already using jQuery, this can also be done with

```
$("span.common-class:not(.ignore):first").css('color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible. The selector `:first-child:not(.ignore)` selects an element that is the first child of its parent and does not belong to class `ignore`. There is no “first of class” selector and no “first not of class” selector either.

You could use the selector `.ignore + :not(.ignore)`, but it matches any element that is not in class `ignore` and immediately follows an element in that class. But it matches too much, not just the first one of such elements. Depending on the markup structure, this selector might still be suitable in a particular situation, even though it is not an answer to the general question asked.

Comment: I use the selector you suggested `.ignore + :not(.ignore)`, but to avoid too much elements I added a class to the parent div (`parent-class`) and used this selector `.parent-class > .ignore + :not(.ignore)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to select the div using a class. What about other css solutions like nth-child etc.? Of course, this requires the knowledge of a document structure.

Comment: Not an answer. Should have been posted as a comment, if at all.

Comment: Well, it depends on real setting, maybe it is fixed structure, although I acknowledge I misinterpreted the question. Peace and love

Answer (score 0):

```
div.someClass + div:not(.someClass) {...}
```

This selects the first div with no `someClass`, which immediately follows one with `someClass`. Hope it helps even though it does not single-out the first no-class div occurrence if multiple "class+no-class pairs" are present. (Run snippet to see example)

```css
 body{background-color:black; color:white}
div.someClass {background-color:darkgreen}
div.someClass + div:not(.someClass) {background-color:brown}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">some class</div>
<div class="someClass">some class</div>
<div>no-class following div.someClass</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div class="someClass">some class</div>
<div>no-class following div.someClass again!</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
<div>no class</div>
```