# :first-child Where Class is :not(.disabled)

Tags: css

I'm trying to select the first element in a list which doesn't have the class="disabled". Anyone know how to pull this off?

Comment: Without  the HTML we can't possibly comment sensibly

Comment: @Paulie_D why? The question is perfectly clear and valid without sample HTML. No clue why this question is getting downvotes and close votes.

Comment: My questions are angel crack.

Answer (score 2):

This is sadly not possible *directly* in CSS, due to the way selectors are organized.

You can however hack around it by using both a positive and a negative selector, first selecting all non-disabled items and styling them, and then using the general sibling selector `~` to *unstyle* the others:

```css
.disabled {
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
li:not(.disabled):after {
  content:" (THIS IS THE FIRST NON DISABLED ITEM)";
}
li:not(.disabled) ~ li:not(.disabled):after {
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="disabled">Item</li>
  <li class="disabled">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="disabled">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="disabled">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the tricks, full credits to [BoltClock♦](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166234/css-first-child-without-certain-class)

```css
li:not(.disabled) {
  /* Every li without class .disabled, including the first */
  background: red;
}

li:not(.disabled) ~ li:not(.disabled) {
  /* Revert above declarations for every such element after the first */
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="disabled">disabled</li>
  <li class="disabled">disabled</li>
  <li class="not-disabled">not-disabled</li>
  <li class="disabled">disabled</li>
  <li class="disabled">disabled</li>
  <li class="disabled">disabled</li>
  <li class="disabled">disabled</li>
  <li class="not-disabled">not-disabled</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
li:first-child:not(.disabled),
li.disabled + li:not(.disabled) {
  /* ...your code. */
}
```