# CSS: Selector on first child, except if in a sub-tag of a certain class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25166234/5181219), except the structure of my file is:

```
<div>
    <p><span class="ignore">blah</span></p>
    <p>blih</p>
    <p>blouh</p>
</div>
```

I want to have a CSS selector on `blih`. If the `span` tag is absent, the selector should apply to `blah` instead.

I can't use `div > p:not(.ignore):first-child` since the `ignore` class applies to the `span` tag, not the `p` tag. I can't apply the `ignore` class to the `p` tag, since this is generated from Markdown.

Is there a CSS selector that does the job, and avoids having to add a `span` tag to `blih`?

Comment: you cannot, the duplicate isn't trivial but basically you need to *not* select the p that contain that span (you need a parent selector for this) ... if you are able to select that p then you will face another difficulty which is nth-child doesn't exclude elements (explained in the question you linked)

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure I understand why the question is a duplicate, but I understand why what I'm asking for is impossible. Thanks!

Comment: like I explained, the missing part of your *puzzle* is a parent selector. If you have it then you can do what you want. And the duplicate explain that a parent selector is still not possible --> so your whole thing is impossible (thus the duplicate)