# Why CSS selector :first-child:not(.ignore) doesn't exclude `ignore` class from selection?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I use `:first-child` with `:not(.ignore)` in order to select every element that is the first child of its parent, unless that first child is of class `ignore`?

What I've tried: `:first-child:not(.ignore){...}`,`:first-child :not(.ignore){...}`, I've also came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166234/css-first-child-without-certain-class), which is phrased as if it was what I am looking for, however the person asking didn't seem to understand how the `:first-child` selector works. Apart from that, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25166331/13459666) suggests that `:first-child:not(.ignore){...}` should work exactly as I expect it to, but for me it just doesn't.

My question is: Am I missing something with syntax or it is just not possible to combine selectors in this way?

```css
:first-child:not(.ingore){
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body >
        <div>
            <div>
                should be blue and is blue
            </div>
            <div>
                should also be blue as it's parent is blue due to being first child of 'body'
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <div class="ignore">
                should not be blue but is blue 
            </div>
            <div>
                should not be blue and is not blue
            </div>
        </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: You made a spelling error: `ingore !== ignore`

Comment: also be more specific becase `:first-child:not(.ingore)` will also select the body element and html one so the background will logically apply to everything

Comment: @TemaniAfif - The `body` element isn't a `:first-child`. The `head` element is its previous sibling.

Comment: @Quentin yes, if we consider a well formatted code

Comment: @TemaniAfif — Even if we don't consider well formatted code. The parsing rules for HTML are very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you made a spelling error. `ingore` and `ignore` don't match.

Aside from that, the `html` element matches your selector, and the default `background-color` for a `div` is `transparent`.

So the selector isn't matching the div and turning it blue, you can just see the blue background of the `html` element through it.

```css
body :first-child:not(.ignore){
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      should be blue and is blue
    </div>
    <div>
      should also be blue as it's parent is blue due to being first child of 'body'
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="ignore">
      should not be blue but is blue
    </div>
    <div>
      should not be blue and is not blue
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am sorry that I didn't notice that spelling mistake. However, are you sure that everything that's inside `<html> ... </html>` matches `:first-child` selector? For me it seems like it only matches what's inside `<body>` element anyways, so `body :first-child` seems redundant. Also, if `html` element matched my selector, the entire page would be blue, which is not the case

Comment: "However, are you sure that everything that's inside `<html> ... </html>` matches :first-child selector" — That isn't what I said. I said `<html>` **itself** matches `:first-child`

Comment: "For me it seems like it only matches what's inside `<body>` element anyways" — It doesn't. That's the problem.

Comment: "if html element matched my selector, the entire page would be blue, which is not the case" — The whole page **is** blue in the live demo in your question!!

Comment: It's strange that the whole page is blue in my live demo for you, here is how it appears on my machine: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GeoaWPpnRZ9QkK-Ozl6fmHXwLzNdn4YV/view?usp=sharing). I.e. last line is not blue.